# Tensor confusion: scalar $\otimes$ vector = OK?...

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra, bilinear-form

I am trying to understand tensors and one particular question have caused me a great deal of confusion. The particular example with the metric tensor below is an attempt to highlight where my confusion is.

In my understanding, one can view the metric tensor $g$ as a bilinear map $g:V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
And one can construct it using the tensor product of dual vectors from $V^{*}$ as below:
$$
g=g_{ij} \mathbf{\epsilon^{i}} \otimes \mathbf{\epsilon^{j}}
$$

If we now put a vector $\mathbf{v}=v^{k}\mathbf{e}_{k}$ in the first argument:

$$
g_{ij} \mathbf{\epsilon^{i}}(v^{k}\mathbf{e_{k}}) \otimes \mathbf{\epsilon^{j}}
$$

$$\Rightarrow 
g_{ij} v^{k} \mathbf{\epsilon^{i}}(\mathbf{e_{k}}) \otimes \mathbf{\epsilon^{j}}
$$

$$\Rightarrow 
g_{ij} v^{k} \delta _{k}^{i} \otimes \mathbf{\epsilon^{j}}
$$

$$\Rightarrow 
g_{ij} v^{i} \mathbf{\epsilon^{j}}
$$

**Now the question:** How can we in the last step remove the tensor product sign? How can we have the $\delta _{k}^{i}$ (a scalar) "tensor multiplied" by a dual vector? Surely you cant put a scalar on one side of the $\otimes$-sign and a vector on the other?...
Thanks on beforehand.

Comment: You can remove $\otimes$ already in the first step when $\epsilon^\mathbf{i}$ eats that vector.

Comment: Do you know any mathematically rigorous explanation behind this?

Comment: $\mathbf{\epsilon^{i}} \otimes \mathbf{\epsilon^{j}}$ is a bilinear form. When one of its slots eats a vector we have a linear form with one slot. That linear form does not need the $\otimes\,.$ (Without doing harm we could say that $a \otimes \mathbf{\epsilon^{j}}$ is ordinary multiplication when $a$ is a number but I have never seen it and it would be quite a ponderous notation.)

Comment: The definition of a tensor product is $e^i \otimes e^j (x,y) := e^i(x) e^j(y)$ where $x,y \in V$ and $e^i, e^j \in V^*$. If we leave the second argument empty then   $e^i \otimes e^j (x,-) := e^i(x) e^j(-)$. Then since $e^i(x)=x^i$ we are left with $x^i e^j(-)$. Use the index lowering property of the metric tensor and $g_{ij}x^i e^j(-)=x_j e^j(-)$ is a covector. Effectively what you have done is define the map from $V$ to $V^*$ so that for every $x \in V$ we can define a covector $\tilde x \in V^*$ via the linear map $g(x,-)$. You just wrote $g(x,-)$ as $g_{ij} e^i \otimes e^j (x,-)$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that
$$
g_{ij} e^i \otimes e^j (x,-) = g_{ij} e^i(x) e^j(-)
$$
start with the definition of the tensor product,
$$
e^i \otimes e^j (x,y) := e^i(x) e^j(y)
$$
So,
\begin{equation}
g(x,y)=g_{ij}e^i \otimes e^j (x,y) = g_{ij} e^i(x) e^j(y)
\tag{I} \label{I}
\end{equation}
Since $e^i(x)=x^i$ and $g_{ij}x^i=x_j$,
\begin{equation}
g(x,y)=x_j e^j(y) 
\tag{II} \label{II}
\end{equation}
The r.h.s. of the last equation is a linear map $x_j e^j(-)$ i.e. a covector. Therefore $\tilde x \in V^*$ is,
\begin{equation}
\tilde x (y) = g(x,y)
\end{equation}
which is a nice property of inner product spaces.

Since,
$$
 g(x,-) = g_{ij} e^i \otimes e^j (x,-)
$$
we can combine (\ref{I}) and (\ref{II}) to get,
$$
x_j e^j(-) = g_{ij} e^i \otimes e^j (x,-)
$$
We have already shown that $x_j = g_{ij} e^i(x)$.
It therefore follows that,
$$
 g_{ij} e^i(x) e^j(-) = g_{ij}e^i \otimes e^j (x,-) 
$$
and this is only possible if $e^i \otimes e^j (x,-)=e^i(x)e^j(-)$.